# Redux React Hello World

Tags: webpack, babeljs, redux, es6-module-loader

This is my Hello World Application in React-Redux. There shows no error when I run `npm start` in my command prompt, but when I open it on localhost:3333, its a blank page. I installed `react` `react-dom` `babel` `babel-core` `babel-preset-es2015` `babel-preset-react` `babel-loader` `webpack` `webpcak-dev-server`. My cmd shows that its running on localhost:3333, and bundle is now Valid. Please help out coz this is my last try to react-redux, please do help.

index.html

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <title>Setup</title>
</head>
<body>
  <div id="app"></div>
  <script type="index.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

App.js

```
import React from 'react';
class App extends React.Component {
    render() {
        return <div>Hello</div>
    }
}

export default App
```

main.js

```
import React from 'react';
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom';
import App from './App';
ReactDOM.render(<App />, document.getElementById('app'))
```

package.json

```
{
  "name": "redux1",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "description": "",
  "main": "index.js",
  "scripts": {
    "start": "webpack-dev-server"
  },
  "author": "",
  "license": "ISC",
  "dependencies": {
    "babel": "^6.5.2",
    "react": "^0.14.7",
    "react-dom": "^0.14.7",
    "webpack": "^1.12.14",
    "webpack-dev-server": "^1.14.1"
  }
}
```

webpack.config.js

```
module.exports = {
    entry: './main.js',
    output: {
        path: './',
        filename: 'index.js'
    },
    devServer: {
        inline: true,
        port: 3333
    },
    module: {
        loaders: [
          {
            test:/\.js$/,
            exclude: /node_modules/,
            loader: 'babel',
            query: {
                presets: ['es2015','react']
            }
          }
        ]
    }
}
```

The title `Setup` displays on the browser tab i.e the title of html code is successfully shown on browser

Comment: Any way to Debug this thing?? Its rolling my tears down

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your `webpack.config.js` output filename should be `bundle.js`, which should be same with your index.html

And `index.html` should correct to `<script src="bundle.js"></script>`

Comment: I changed it, still the same.

Comment: @isaksham I review your code again, your package.json dependencies have some big mistakes. You should use `babel-loader` instead of `babel`.

Comment: Still no luck buddy.     "dependencies": {
        "babel": "^6.5.2",
        "babel-core": "^6.6.5",
        "babel-loader": "^6.2.0",
        "react": "^0.14.7",
        "react-dom": "^0.14.7",
        "webpack": "^1.12.14",
        "webpack-dev-server": "^1.14.1"
      }

Comment: No Error thats the problem, I am following this video https://egghead.io/lessons/react-react-fundamentals-development-environment-setup?pl=react-redux-es6-d38bc6dc and I did the same thing. React-Redux should not be this tough to set up.

Comment: Is there any way to debug it??

Answer (score 1):

Finally I found the error, its in html. Instead of `<script type="index.js"></script>` I got to write `<script src="index.js"></script>`.